# Pickle: Storing the contents of variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I kept the module pickle in my directory.
Now, I want to store the variable i.e. Arpan in a created file called spdict.data
So, when i enter the code as follows:

```
    import pickle
    Arpan = "My name is Arpan"
    fh = open("spdict.data","w")
    pickle.dump(Arpan,fh)
    fh.close()
```

I would expect the variable Arpan to get stored, but I get the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\IDLE scripts for bioinfo book\File handling\test1 reading fasta.py", line 173, in 
    pickle.dump(Arpan,fh)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Also, when I enter the program

```
import pickle
Arpan = {"One":1,"Two":2,"Three":3}
fh = open("spdict.data","w")
pickle.dump(Arpan,fh)
fh.close()
```

Then also, following error comes:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\IDLE scripts for bioinfo book\File handling\test1 reading fasta.py", line 173, in 
    pickle.dump(Arpan,fh)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Please help.. My python version is 3.6.4

Answer (score 1):

When writing pickles, open your files for binary writing.

```
fh = open("spdict.data", "wb")
```

Comment: Now, when I try to retrieve it by the following code, 
        fh = open("spdict.data")
        Arpan = pickle.load(fh)
        print(Arpan)
        fh.close()                                    it gives a following error line 180, in <module>
    Arpan = pickle.load(fh)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Yes, I tried the first solution, it worked.. and then when I tried to retrieve the stored variable 'Arpan', I got stuck up with the above error.. Please excuse me for my ignorance.

Comment: Ok, I tried retrieving in binary form.. and it worked..Thanks all.